# "remote management module" and "active management technology": What is the difference?

Tags: intel, hardware

I am considering the following motherboard: http://ark.intel.com/products/56334/NULL?wapkw=intel+s2600cp4+ssi+eeb

This motherboard includes support for an Intel Remote Management Module (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/server-management/intel-remote-management-module.html), which allows the capability of performing remote restarts of crashed/hung/powered down machines - but it does *not* include support for "Active Management Technology", also an Intel protocol, which also allows for remote power capabilities.

I cannot find a discussion of the difference between these two technologies anywhere.

Can someone please explain the difference between "remote management module" technology, and "active management technology"?

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, as best as I can determine,

- Remote Management - allows you to reboot the server and then act as if you were sitting it at, remotely.  Intended to be connected to directly (i.e. to get a remote console)
- Active Management - works out of band (i.e. server can be powered 'down') and allows you to query the hardware and other associated management actions, not intended to be connected to directly, but instead to be used used by remote 3rd party software.

Comment: However, I believe Remote Management is also out-of-band and allows you to access BIOS and the hardware.